# Alter VIEW restrictions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created the below VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW games_lost as 
    select p.id, p.name, count(m.loser) as ng
    from players p left join matches m 
    on p.id=m.loser
    where m.tournament_id = 0
    group by p.id, p.name;
```

I wish to update the WHERE for a given tournament_id's.
Had a look at the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-alterview.html) but didn't find an explanation how to do it.

Comment: But why a view specific for a tournament_id? Have one general games_lost view. (Or at least add tournament_id to the view name...)

Comment: A view must be generic. You can apply your condition on tournament_id where instantiate the view. I.e. SELECT * FROM games_lost where id_torunament in (1,2,3....)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  You have to use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` and recreate the whole thing from scratch.  From [the Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-alterview.html):

> `ALTER VIEW` changes various auxiliary properties of a view. **(If you want to modify the view's defining query, use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`.)**

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misconception about the use of views here. A view is used in SELECT-queries exactly like a table.

You could regularly replace the view with CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW but this would be **very** poor design.

So my suggestion is that the view returned results from all tournaments grouped by tournament id:

```
CREATE VIEW games_lost as 
    select p.id, p.name, m.tournament_id, count(m.loser) as ng
    from players p left join matches m 
    on p.id=m.loser
    group by p.id, p.name,m.tournament_id;
```

Then in the code you would query the view with the specific id in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT id, name, ng FROM games_lost WHERE tournament_id = 0;
```